# Python Panda based Split and group json line file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I am new to Python and Panda, have a use case to read a json line file, split lines based on "category" attribute and write them to another json line file named category.json which will be created from code.**

This can be done in other libraries but wanted to know how to do it in Panda.
Any help is appreciated

```
Input input json line file:
{"header": {"category": "A", "type": "type1"}, "payload": {"attr1": "a1","attr2": "a2"}}
{"header": {"category": "A", "type": "type2"}, "payload": {"attr1": "b1","attr2": "b2"}}
{"header": {"category": "B", "type": "type3"}, "payload": {"attr11": "c1","attr22": "c2", "attr33":"c3"}}
{"header": {"category": "B", "type": "type4"}, "payload": {"attr11": "d1","attr22": "d2", "attr33":"d3"}}
```

Two file need to be created: A.json and B.json
I managed to read the file using:

```
df = pd.read_json('input.json', lines=True)
categories = pd.DataFrame(df.header.values.tolist())['category'].values
print(categories)
```

Above returns:
["A", "A", "B", "B"]

Now am thinking to read this list and apply groupby here.
Is my approach correct, or its making the simple stuff complicated.

I also need to transpose before writing them into category wise file.

Expected Output:

A.json

```
type  attr1  attr2
type1  a1    a2
type2  b1    b2
```

B.json

```
type  attr11  attr22  attr33
type3   c1    c2      c3
type4   d1    d2      d3
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to show us the sample output of the final dataframes/files.

Comment: Hi @SomeDude Thanks for super fast reply. Have updated the question with expected output. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save multiple `json` files, you can do:

```py
df = pd.read_json("input.json", lines=True)

df = pd.concat(
    [df["header"].apply(pd.Series), df["payload"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1
)

for v, g in df.groupby("category"):
    g = g.drop(columns="category")
    g.to_json("{}.json".format(v))
    print(g)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
    type attr1 attr2
0  type1    a1    a2
1  type2    b1    b2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    type attr1 attr2
2  type3    c1    c2
3  type4    d1    d2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And saves `A.json` and `B.json`

---

EDIT: With different `input.json`:

```py
df = pd.read_json("input.json", lines=True)

df = pd.concat(
    [df["header"].apply(pd.Series), df["payload"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1
)


for v, g in df.groupby("category"):
    g = g.drop(columns="category")
    g = g.dropna(axis=1, how="all")  # <-- drop columns with all NaNs
    g.to_json("{}.json".format(v))
    print(g)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
    type attr1 attr2
0  type1    a1    a2
1  type2    b1    b2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    type attr11 attr22 attr33
2  type3     c1     c2     c3
3  type4     d1     d2     d3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Reply was lightening fast. Thanks for this working solution. I will break it step and step and try to understand. The above for loop is easy to understand. Just need to get the hold of the use of apply method with Series here. Thanks once again :)

Comment: In the above approach, if I have let say, category A has attr1 and attr2 whereas category B has attr11 and attr22. In this since the attributes names are different, panda will not allow to transpose first as the column names are different.  Can we do this transpose later. I will update the input and output in the question. It was my failure to provide the most realistic input and output earlier.

Comment: Updated the question with more realistic input and output. Please pardon me for the previous input data.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks Again :)